# Has the Trump administration so far responded to any of the "We the people" petitions?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, petition

I am curious on if the Trump administration has responded to any of the petitions that received over 100K signatures on [petitions.whitehouse.gov](https://petitions.whitehouse.gov).

On [this FAQ page](https://petitions.whitehouse.gov/about#step-by-step) the White House says...

> The White House will respond to petitions submitted through We the
>   People that comply with these Terms of Participation and reach the
>   second signature threshold listed below.

...and this of course does give an impression of commitment on their part.

Also my reason for asking is because the White House may have provided a response but it may not have received much attention in the news media. For example I would be curious about this ["Immediately release Donald Trump's full tax returns..." petition](https://petitions.whitehouse.gov/petition/immediately-release-donald-trumps-full-tax-returns-all-information-needed-verify-emoluments-clause-compliance) for which I cannot tell from the page if it is being ignored or if they may have responded to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Background

The petitions site is a holdover from the Barack Obama administration.  I don't know that Donald Trump has made any commitment to it whatsoever.  The current system seems to be left over from the Obama administration.  It's not clear the Trump administration plans on doing anything with it.

Beyond that, Obama didn't commit to do the things in the petitions.  He pledged to address them.  Saying "No, we're not doing that" would address the petition.

You can still view the [Obama petitions](https://petitions.obamawhitehouse.archives.gov/).  A denied petition:  [Designate India as a terrorist state](https://petitions.obamawhitehouse.archives.gov/petition/republic-india-involved-spreading-terrorism-pakistan-and-should-be-declared-terrorist-state).

There are several other petitions where they basically say that it is not within the president's authority to accomplish whatever it might be.  This includes saying that congressional action is required, as is true of the two featured petitions.  In [one case](https://petitions.obamawhitehouse.archives.gov/petition/we-people-ask-congress-meet-emergency-session-about-removing-george-soros-owned-voting-machines-16-states), they note that it is a state issue, not a federal issue.

#### Answer

With that background, the Trump administration does not appear to have responded to any of the petitions (as of November 29th, 2017).  Responses should show [here](https://petitions.whitehouse.gov/responses#petitionswithupdates).  Also, on the [main page](https://petitions.whitehouse.gov/), the link that currently says "Sign It" would change to "View".